# This system of linear equations seems not to be a linear system, why?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

this question comes from this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3275689/684611) and [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations)

> a system of linear equations (or linear system) is a collection of two
>   or more linear equations involving the same set of variables. For
>   example,

$${\displaystyle {\begin{alignedat}{7}3x&&\;+\;&&2y&&\;-\;&&z&&\;=\;&&1&\\2x&&\;-\;&&2y&&\;+\;&&4z&&\;=\;&&-2&\\-x&&\;+\;&&{\tfrac {1}{2}}y&&\;-\;&&z&&\;=\;&&0&\end{alignedat}}}
$$

according this definition, the equation in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3275689/684611)

$$
\displaystyle \left[\begin{matrix}x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13}\\x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23}\\x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33}\end{matrix}\right]
\Sigma = 
\displaystyle \left[\begin{matrix}\sqrt{10} x_{11} & 0\\\sqrt{10} x_{21} & 0\\\sqrt{10} x_{31} & 0\end{matrix}\right]
$$

is not a linear system, since there is no `same set of variables`

this conclusion seems to be wrong, but why?

Comment: Are your $x_{ij}$ given and $\Sigma$ your unknown matrix?

Comment: @Lance $x_{ij}$ is unknown and $\Sigma$ is given. Is the original post (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3275689/684611) not clear enough? if yes, please tell me which part needs to be improved.

Comment: Thank you. I would say the original post would be clearer if you wrote, "let unknown matrix consist of unknown variables $x_{ij}$".

Answer (score 1):

It is not at all clear what the constraint "involving the same set of variables" in the definition actually means.

If the $x_{ij}$ are unknowns and $\Sigma$ contains six given values then the six equations are linear in the nine $x_{ij}$ unknowns, even though each equation only involves three of the nine unknowns. So this is a system of linear equations.

But you can split the six equations into three independent pairs of equations - there are two equations that involve $x_{11}, x_{12}, x_{13}$ and no other unknonwns, for example.

So it might be more precise to say that the six equations represent three separate systems of linear equations, with two equations and three unknowns in each system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this specific case, the $\Sigma$ contains six given values, and 5 of them are 0. Should I still consider this six given values?

Comment: @soplus2018 Yes, there is nothing special about 0, so you have six given values in $\Sigma$.